# Truck shaking at certain mph or when under load

Tags: engine, transmission, f-150, shaking

**Vehicle Information:**

2006 Ford F150 4WD with the 5.4L V8

150,000 miles (oil change every 5000 miles)

**Background:**

In the fall, I started having problems with my truck. It had a rough idle and would shake at certain mph or when under a load.  I ended up doing some research, and determined that it was my timing chain guides and tensioners.  I ended up taking a weekend to pull the front timing cover off and fix the problem; however, this fixed my rough idle problem, but did not fix my shaking problem, revealing that there was more to the problem than I originally thought.

**Problem:**

To give more details about the problem, my truck has had a very bad shake, as if you were giving over pot holes, but I can't really pinpoint the problem. The shake usually always occurs at very specific mph ranges. It will first happen around **45-50 mph** and again at around **60 mph** It also happens when under additional load, such as driving at a constant speed up a hill. I have been able to mitigate many of problems and lessen there frequency by adapting my driving style around the problem, such as accelerating/increasing my rpm when I'm near the problem areas(45-50 mph, 60 mph, going up a hill).  Also, this problem **does not happen when overdrive is turned off**, so I often find myself switching into overdrive when going up hills or accelerating around 45 mph.

Something else that is strange is that the truck has not thrown a single engine light.

**Define Shaking:**

This is not a rough idle shake, this is a very noticeable, rough, shake. It doesn't feel like any kind of shake I have ever felt before. You can feel it in the steering wheel, the seats, the floor. It is as if something hitting underneath the vehicle.

**Thoughts:**

My first thought was that it was transmission failure, but it doesn't feel like any transmission failure I have ever encounter.  I also thought that it could be engine misfires, but certainly the computer would throw an engine light if that was the case, right?  I less convinced that it is an engine problem.  I think it is more of a transmission or drive train.

Also, during my initial attempts of trying to diagnose the problem, I tried to use a product called Lubegard Instant Shudder Fix to see if it would fix the shaking. This help for a day or two and then went back to the way it was operating before.

---

If anyone has had any experience with this problem or knows what it is, please let me know. Any advice or guidance is encouraged.

**Edit:**
I totally forgot to give and update on the situation... so I was able to figure out at least one of my problems.  The cause of the rough idle was the timing chain, timing chain tensioners, and timing chain belt rails.  I was able to take the front timing cover off the front of the motor and replace the broken tensioners and rails; however, this only fixed the rough idle.

A month or so had went by until I noticed a comment on a similar shaking issue, stating that it could be caused by bad spark plugs, so I ended up changing them and the shaking went away.  This didn't last forever, the shaking came back after about 10,000-15,000 miles...

Because the spark-plugs seemed to fix the problem, I think I can rule out the issue being a transmission or u-joint problem, but instead something like the coils

Comment: So, first thing, you won't *always* get a check engine light for misfires. Best way to verify or eliminate engine issues would be hooking up a scanner. However, you *may* still not get codes. It really depends on the misfire and what exactly is occurring.

Comment: @kyle_engineer I added some more information about the shaking as well as some other information I forgot to add

Comment: updated my response as well.

Comment: Is there any reason to rule out suspension issues? Have you checked for play at the wheels? Have you inspected for possible missing wheel weights?

Comment: Broken belt in your tire ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Lubegard product seemed to help, that would suggest that it's a transmission related issue. *However* that also doesn't necessarily eliminate the other drive components like the hangar bearing.

Take a good look at all the mounting points. You say it feels like something hitting the underside. It very possibly could be. It could even be something like a loose connections between the trans and drive shafts. [This image](https://www.suspension.com/prodimages/moog/moog-ujoint-packagedeal457/moog-moog-ujoint-packagedeal457-large-diagram-2.png) shows each of the u-joint locations. Any one of these in the drive shafts can stick and cause this shuddering.

The first things that I'd recommend checking out is the hanger bearing (#5 in the above image). They can lock under varying torque conditions, which could explain why you don't have the same problem when you had it hard or toggle overdrive.

Answer (score -2):

U-joints guaranteed my man, get under the truck and try to move the drive line up and down see if there's slop